# Vaadin Checking which component has focus

Tags: java, focus, vaadin

Is there a way to find out which component has the actual focus in a Vaadin window!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, at least not directly (which is surprising). Please [follow the links and discussions indicated in the thread on Vaadin forum](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/81657).

You can go around it, but it will require certain amount of work. A starting point is [the `Focusable` interface](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Component.Focusable.html). Basically, you should capture all focus events in all the components.

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution.
The given link "[follow the links and discussions indicated in the thread on Vaadin forum](https://vaadin.com/en/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/81656)" in your answer makes 404 error. Please update your answer if you have got any matured solution.

Comment: @VisruthCV: Vaadin has changed their forum engine to a new one. I updated the post. New link does not seem to work on IE, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a focusListener and a blurListener to each component. If a component has focus you set an object to the current component, if blurListener gets called you set it to null.

If the object is != null you just need to check which component it is and you know which one has focus.